# Flutter : FutureBuilder not updating if data null

Tags: flutter, dart

I have Futurebuilder to showing my data from server. Everthing is ok , i can showing my data and show Icon if data empty.

```
return FutureBuilder<List<Mosque>>(
      future: api.getMahasiswa(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
          case ConnectionState.active:
            return MyWidgetMain.wLoadingIndicator();
            break;
          default:
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return MyWidgetMain.wDataNotFound(); <<<<
            else
              return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListMosque(
                    id: snapshot.data[index].id ?? "",
                    nrp: snapshot.data[index].nrp ?? "",
                    nama: snapshot.data[index].nama ?? "",
                    email: snapshot.data[index].email ?? "",
                    jurusan: snapshot.data[index].jurusan ?? "",
                    image: snapshot.data[index].image ?? "",
                  );
                },
              );
        }
      },
    );
```

But problem is , Example i have some data and i delete it, My Futurebuilder not updating if data empty.

#### it if data empty in Futurebuilder

[image: futurebuilder]

#### It's My Future builder not updating data.

[image: FutureBuilder2]

Can you help me with this ?

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

```
**check data length first. if data length is null then you can show no data found image**
if (snapshot.hasError)
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        else if (snapshot.data != null) {
          int l = snapshot.data.documents.length;
          if (l == 0)
            return Center(child: Image.asset("images/nodatafound.jpg"));
        }
```